# pjsua2 sample(for android) video call rotate -90 degree and throws exception when call setCaptureOrient

Tags: android, video, pjsip

I'm using pjsua2 sample project to make a video call,every thing is well, both the android app client can see and hear each other,but the video is rotate -90 degree.
And in the `CallActivity.java`, it's throws an exception when call `setCaptureOrient(cap_dev, orient, true)`.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    WindowManager wm;
    Display display;
    int rotation;
    pjmedia_orient orient;

    wm = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    rotation = display.getRotation();
    System.out.println("Device orientation changed: " + rotation);

    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:   // Portrait
        orient = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_ROTATE_270DEG;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:  // Landscape, home button on the right
        orient = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_NATURAL;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        orient = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_ROTATE_90DEG;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: // Landscape, home button on the left
        orient = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_ROTATE_180DEG;
        break;
    default:
        orient = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_UNKNOWN;
    }

    if (MyApp.ep != null && MainActivity.account != null) {
        try {
        AccountConfig cfg = MainActivity.account.cfg;
        int cap_dev = cfg.getVideoConfig().getDefaultCaptureDevice();




        //----------here throws an exception:option/operation is not support. ------------

        MyApp.ep.vidDevManager().setCaptureOrient(cap_dev, orient,true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception info:

> media.cpp!pjsua_vid_dev_set_setting(dev_id,PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_CAP_ORIENTATION, &orient, keep) error: Option/operation is not supported (PJ_ENOTSUP) (status=70012) [../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:1483]
>       Description: Option/operation is not supported (PJ_ENOTSUP)

I don't have changed anything,but it just not work,so why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know the cause of the error，it's  that the pjsip source code not support capture orientation setting for ffmpeg libs,which I used.I found it in the : *pjproject/pjmedia/src/pjmedia-videodev/util.c*

```
...
#include "util.h"

#include <pj/assert.h>
#include <pj/errno.h>
#include <pj/log.h>

#if defined(PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO) && (PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO != 0)

#if defined(PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBYUV) && PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBYUV != 0
#include  <libyuv.h>
#define HAS_ROTATION 1
#else
    #define HAS_ROTATION 0     //the reason why ffmpeg not support capture orientation setting
#endif

#define THIS_FILE       "vid_util.c"

pj_status_t
pjmedia_vid_dev_conv_create_converter(pjmedia_vid_dev_conv *conv,
                  pj_pool_t *pool,
                  pjmedia_format *fmt,
                  pjmedia_rect_size src_size,
                  pjmedia_rect_size dst_size,
                  pj_bool_t handle_rotation,
                  pj_bool_t maintain_aspect_ratio)
{
    pj_status_t status;
    pjmedia_conversion_param conv_param;
    const pjmedia_video_format_info *vfi;   

    pj_assert((src_size.w == dst_size.w || src_size.h == dst_size.h) ||
          (src_size.w == dst_size.h || src_size.h == dst_size.w));

if (conv->conv)
    return PJ_SUCCESS;

if (fmt->id != PJMEDIA_FORMAT_I420 && fmt->id != PJMEDIA_FORMAT_BGRA)
    return PJ_EINVAL;

/* Currently, for BGRA format, device must handle the rotation. */
if (fmt->id == PJMEDIA_FORMAT_BGRA && handle_rotation)
    return PJ_ENOTSUP;

if (handle_rotation) {
#if !HAS_ROTATION
return PJ_ENOTSUP; // return ffmpeg not support capture orientation setting error
#endif
}
...
```

Comment: may i ask how can i make video call from pjsua2 sample app